# Настройка NSPredicate для нескольких языков

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Если такая проблема: есть некий список названий (ФИО, названия академических групп в университете) на украинском языке, и множество русскоязычных пользователей, которые предпочли бы искать эти названия на русском языке. Для вывода использую tableView, и поиск происходит через UISearchController. При этом предикат настроен так:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];
```

Можно ли как-нибудь изменить настройки предиката, чтобы он одинаково срабатывал как на русскую "и", так и на украинскую "і"? Тоже самое касается русской "е" и украинской "є".

Я пробовал заменить символы, как в примере ниже, но это не совсем то что нужно.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[c] %@", [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"и" withString:@"і"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не скажу насколько будет правильно по примеру, но в данном случае используйте регулярки.

```
predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[c] %@"
```

замените на

```
predicateWithFormat:@"title MATCHES [cd] %@"
```

А искомую строку приводите к виду:

```
@"^(.*?)[иі]мя(.*?)"
```

Как пример для быстрой проверки:

```
NSString *name = @"Это имя Иван";
NSString *searchText = @"^(.*?)[иі]ван(.*?)";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES [cd] %@", searchText];
NSLog(@"содержит: %d", [predicate evaluateWithObject:name]);
```